# CSS Framework / Showcase for Arrangement of Divs with Dynamic With and Height

Tags: html, css-frameworks

I am searching a css framework/way for the following use case:

[image: layout]

I need to be able to position divs with dynamic width and height on a grid system in an optimal way. Moreover, the layout needs to be responsive. E.g. if the Browser Window gets big enough to show a fourth colon, the divs should be rearranged on four columns. Moreover 2, the height of the divs can be dynamic and therefore trigger a rearrangement.

Is there a CSS grid system/framework which supports this use case? Or is there an "easy" way to do it in CSS? Does someone know a showcase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you need something like Masonry, Isotope, or Packery.